# Why does adding two array lengths sum their index values instead of summing value of their actual length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I can see that the function is adding output[19] to output[18] to generate a sum of 4181, however why is the sum not 37?

```js
function fibonacciGenerator(n) {

  var output = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i < 2) {
      output.push(i)
    } else {
      output.push(output[output.length - 1] + output[output.length - 2])
    }
  }
  console.log(output);
}

fibonacciGenerator(20);
```

Comment: Because `output[19]` will resolve to the value of index `19` of the array `output`. If you want to sum `19` and `18`, then you need `19 + 18`

Comment: I see, so by stating .length within the [index] I'm saying take the index values at that position by shorting the length of the array and logging what you find at that shortened place? Excuse me if that didn't make the most sense, however I believe I understand what you're saying.

Comment: `output.length - 1` is just the last index in the array (because indexing starts at 0). Similarly `output.length - 2` is the second to last index. This `output[output.length - 1]` is the last item in the array and `output[output.length - 2]` is the second to last item.

Comment: output[19] or output[18] gives you the element which is in 18th or 19th position of the array. if you need 37 just add the indexes you are asking. not the elements. output[output.length - 1] gives you the element in the index of output.length - 1 ,(output.length - 1) is the index which is 18 or 19. (output.length - 1) + (output.length - 2) will give you 37

Comment: Got it, so I'm saying add output[index value first to last] + output[index value 2nd to last] so that's summing their actual values found at those indexes and not just summing the two different lengths of the array which would be a much small number. That makes perfect sense. Thank you everyone!

Comment: @VLAZ could you please explain to me why output.length - 1 is accessing the last index in the array just because indexing starts at 0? Why not starting at index 0 and give me the value of the first index in the array instead of the last? Thank you.

Comment: @vash2022 well, if you have 3 items in the array (`array.length == 3`), then you have an item at indexes `0`, `1`, and `2`. If you add one more, then `.length` is `4` and the last index is now `3`. So, in general, you always have the length as one more than the last index.

Comment: @VLAZ I see! That makes sense, so I'm saying (output.length - 1 is 7) and at output[7] is the final value of my array which is 8 elements long starting at output[0], but we must start counting from output[0] as the first element meaning the final one would be at index[7] - which is the sum that was generated by output[output.length -1] . Makes total sense. Thank you so much.

Comment: `output[anything]` accesses the element at that index. There's nothing special about using `output.length-1` as the index.